# Example to calculate dates using useState in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Good nigth!

I need of an example of how calculate the difference between two dates using the useState of the Hooks in React.js. I try do this, but I eceived an error: Objects are not valid as a React child.

```
const [dateBegin, setDateBegin] = useState(new Date())
const [dateEnd, setDateEnd] = useState(new Date())
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and the code that is causing this error?

Comment: this means you can't render f.e. {dateBegin} (as this is an object), you can render dates converted to string

Comment: I tried to use new Date() and I believe that it is the error. My question is: How to use an date object in the useState hook?

Comment: Try to save date like: `new Date().toString()` and display it however you want to show it.

Answer (score -1):

Put your dates in a variable in a object.

```
const [dateBegin, setDateBegin] = useState({varOne:new Date()})
const [dateEnd, setDateEnd] = useState({varTwo:new Date()})
```